# Intellij GIT - Push to branch all changes since clone

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I cloned a project and I've been pushing my changes to a branch.
Now I want to push all the changes since the clone (not only the last commit) to a new branch I'll create; but when I go to VCS->GIT->Push in the right panel I see that only the changes made since the last push are selected. How can I tell intellij to push all changes since the clone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push dialog show only commits that are not present in the remote repository. Effectively, that is only your last commit.

Any branch you create on the remote from your current HEAD will contain all the commits you did since clone anyway.

Comment: thanks, you are right. I did a push to a new branch (it was created when I did the push) and all changes where pushed, not only the last ones

Answer (score 1):

*VCS > Git > Push* will show all un-pushed changes. It will not show pushed changes, even ones pushed to/on another branch. To view all commits (regardless of their being pushed or not) you can:

1. Go to the **Version Control** tool window and
2. then to the *Log* tab.
3. You can filter the view to show only commits to a articular view.

[image]

> Now I want to push all the changes since the clone (not only the last commit) to a new branch I'll create

You'll need to **merge** the changes from the original branch to the new branch. You can do this in two ways.

### Option 1 - merge the entire branch

Switch to the target branch (the new branch you want to merge the changes *to*). In the bottom right of the IntelliJ IDEA window, open the VCS dialog by clicking the double arrows:

[image]

In the popup, select *{source branch} > merge*. For example, here I'm merging from "my-work-branch" branch to "the-target-branch" branch:

[image]

You should then get a confirmation of the merge.

[image]

**All** changes made on the source branch will not be merged onto the target branch. You can then push those.

### Option 2 - Cherry Picking

Switch to the target branch (the new branch you want to merge the changes *to*). From the *Log* tab of the **Version Control** tool window (see above), select the individual commits form the source branch you want to merge to the new branch. (Hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to select multiple commits, or the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to select a consecutive group). Click the cherry pick button [image] from the Version Control tool bar (or right click and select it from the context menu).